# How to check location of Window7 in java

Tags: java

Is there any method in java Language to find out ; that in which Folder(C:\ , D:\ etc ..) , the Microsoftware Windows 7 operation system is installed . There is a method

```
                  System.getProperty("user.home").toLowerCase();
```

to find out the User Location which is in the same folder in which Operating System(C:\, D:\ etc..) is installed , but i want to know if any other method exists or not ?

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Why do you believe user.home has to be on the same drive as the system?

Comment: They are not of course; on my work computer my user directory has been moved to D:\ while the operating system is still on the far more protected C:\. Its the type of assumption that leads to "works on my machine" issue rejections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get value of system env. variable `%SYSTEMROOT%`. To do this use:

`System.getenv().get("SystemRoot")` or `System.getenv().get("windir")`

**UPD:** To see full list of system variables:

```
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
        System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                envName,
                env.get(envName));
    }
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

Comment: @icza Sure, they should be, of course. Updated my answ. Thanks